# Hadoop : Reducer class not called even with Overrides

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying a mapreduce wordcount code in hadoop, but the reducer class is never called and the program terminates after running the mapper class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();
    @Override 
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {


     @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

I have even Overridden the classes as required.

IDE : Eclipse Luna
Hadoop : version 2.5

Comment: Does it terminate successfully? Any error messages? Did you check the logs?

Comment: It terminates successfully returning 0.

Comment: The weirdest part was that it does this only when running in eclipse. But not when I run it directly using hadoop cli.

Comment: Can you post output of job?

Answer (score 0):

A Job object forms the specification of the job and gives you control over how the job is run. When we run this job on a Hadoop cluster, we will package the code into a JAR file (which Hadoop will distribute around the cluster).

Rather than explicitly specify the name of the JAR file, we can pass a class in the Job's setJarByClass() method, which Hadoop will use to locate the relevant JAR file by looking for the JAR file containing this class.

I do not see the statement in the main method. Hence, include this and then compile and run the code.

job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);